# Props function valid in one Component but not another of the same class

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i'm trying to render 2 different components of the same class.
The props function `handleClick` that was passed, is not rendered in the component.
This conclusion was made from referring to the source code of the html.

---

[1st component rendered successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWcPN.png)

[2nd component rendered but incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFMDO.png)

---

```
class Switch extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let type = this.props.type;
        console.log("type:", type);
        return (
            <div id={ type.concat("-switch") }>
                <label className="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id={ type } name={ type } value={ type } onClick={ this.props.handleClick }/>
                    <span className="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

Any form of help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Comment: Please show how the Switch component is being used

Comment: AHHHH!!! i saw the mistake. Thank you so much for your tip! Sorry about that! It was a silly mistake on my end. I'm new here. So should i delete this post?